# How many ways are there to pick r objects from n objects when repetitions are allowed and ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> How many ways are there to pick r objects from n objects when
>   repetitions are allowed and either both the first and the second
>   objects appear exactly once or both do not appear?

So here is what I tried and I'm not sure if it's correct.

If we have n bins and each bin is an object, and we choose each object once we will have r-n, but since the first and second object appear once or not at all we have r-(n-2)+-2, at least I think. So using

$n+k-1 \choose k$

I think I can get

$n+(r-(n-2)\pm2)-1 \choose k$

Is this correct? I dont think it is, but I'm not sure how else to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply separate the $2$ cases:

**1 and 2 element don't appear**

This means that we must choose $r$ elements with repetition, from $n-2$ elements:

$${{n-2+r-1}\choose{r-1}}={{n+r-3}\choose{r-1}}$$

**1 and 2 element appear one time**

This time we have to select $r-2$ elements with repetition, from $n-2$ elements:

$${{n-2+r-2-1}\choose{r-2-1}}={{n+r-5}\choose{r-3}}$$

Since the two cases are disjoint, the result is the sum of them:

$${{n+r-5}\choose{r-3}}+{{n+r-3}\choose{r-1}}$$

Comment: Sorry if the following is obvious, but I'm still a beginner. In the first case why is it (r-1) at the bottom and not just r? In the second case we are picking 1 and 2 once, and everything else can be picked with repetitions. I understand this, but I don't get how that translates to using r-2 and n-2, wouldn't n-2, make 1 and 2 not appear?

Comment: @Brownie If you want to select $r$ objects from $n$ and the order doesn't matter and each object can be reapeted than the general formula is: ${{n+r-1}\choose{r-1}}$ or ${{n+r-1}\choose{n}}$

Comment: Oh alright thanks! I wasn't using the general formula correctly. One last thing, so in the second case, you do r-2 because that's how man you are doing with repetition, and then you do n-2, because objects 1 and 2 aren't used. If I'm understanding this correct, when do you factor in the fact that they appear once?

Comment: @Brownie since we fixed them and they don't appear anymore in the formula ($n-2$) they appear only $1$ time.